# How to apply an operation in a column based on a condition from another column

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a simple division in a new column of my df. The condition is that when the code find a std flag on the type column use this number to divide the isoprene_area column until it find the next std value. The main problem is that there is no pattern between flags so I have no idea how to get what I need.

This is my df. It has approx 15000 rows.

```
                    tft   type isoprene_area
466 2019-01-25 05:27:00 sample      4
467 2019-01-25 06:43:00    std      8
468 2019-01-25 08:02:00   blnk      1
469 2019-01-25 09:12:00 sample      1
470 2019-01-25 10:17:00 sample      1
471 2019-01-25 11:20:00 sample      1
```

This is the output I am expecting to get

```
                    tft   type isoprene_area result
466 2019-01-25 05:27:00 sample      4     NA
467 2019-01-25 06:43:00    std      8     1
468 2019-01-25 08:02:00   blnk      1     .12
469 2019-01-25 09:12:00 sample      1     .12
470 2019-01-25 10:17:00 sample      1     .12
471 2019-01-25 11:20:00 sample      1     .12
466 2019-01-25 05:27:00 sample      1     .12
467 2019-01-25 06:43:00    std      2     1
468 2019-01-25 08:02:00   blnk      1     .5
469 2019-01-25 09:12:00 sample      1     .5
470 2019-01-25 10:17:00 sample      1     .5
471 2019-01-25 11:20:00 sample      1     .5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave` by creating groups every time `"std"` value is encountered and divide the entire group with `std` value in the group.

```
df$result <- with(df, isoprene_area/ave(isoprene_area, 
            cumsum(type == "std"), FUN = function(x) x[1]))

df
#                  tft   type isoprene_area result
#1  2019-01-2505:27:00 sample             4  1.000
#2  2019-01-2506:43:00    std             8  1.000
#3  2019-01-2508:02:00   blnk             1  0.125
#4  2019-01-2509:12:00 sample             1  0.125
#5  2019-01-2510:17:00 sample             1  0.125
#6  2019-01-2511:20:00 sample             1  0.125
#7  2019-01-2505:27:00 sample             1  0.125
#8  2019-01-2506:43:00    std             2  1.000
#9  2019-01-2508:02:00   blnk             1  0.500
#10 2019-01-2509:12:00 sample             1  0.500
#11 2019-01-2510:17:00 sample             1  0.500
#12 2019-01-2511:20:00 sample             1  0.500
```

If you want `NA`s till the first `std` value we can do

```
df$result[1 : (which.max(df$type == "std") - 1)] <- NA
```

---

OR with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(group = cumsum(type == "std")) %>%
 mutate(result = isoprene_area/first(isoprene_area))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the dplyr code worked good. Is there a way that i can use to apply this same logic to all my columns in a df?. Knowing that I already have the group column which identify every chunk of data.

Comment: You can use `mutate_at` and include column numbers, names or range of column numbers and name to apply the same function for multiple columns. Something like `df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(type == "std")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(isoprene_area), ~ ./first(.))`